# Is there a bullet proof way to ensure no white screen shows with the Capacitor Splash Screen plugin?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm having some issues with my app displaying a blank white screen for a brief moment after the Splash Screen disappears and before the app UI loads. I have been searching around for some examples for how to correct this issue and everything I have attempted does not appear to correct the issue.

This is my `capacitor.config.ts` file:

```
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
    appId: 'com.ionic.io',
    appName: 'Example App',
    webDir: 'www',
    bundledWebRuntime: false,
    plugins: {
        SplashScreen: {
            launchAutoHide: false,
            launchShowDuration: 3000,
            showSpinner: false,
        }
    },
};
```

My `app.component.ts` file:

```
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(
        private platform: Platform
    ) {
        this.initializeApp();
    }

    async initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.setStyle({ 
                style: Style.Dark 
            });
            StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({
                color: '#4c9caf'
            });
            SplashScreen.hide();
        });

        
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am not doing any background data processing that should delay the app from loading after the Splash Screen has gone away. Is there a better way to be managing the SplashScreen display and hide?

Additionally, here is a run down of my environment and plugins:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.17.0 (/Users/XXXXXX/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.11
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.0.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.0.5
   @angular/cli                  : 12.0.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.1.1
   @capacitor/android : 3.1.2
   @capacitor/core    : 3.1.2
   @capacitor/ios     : 3.1.1

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.3
   native-run (update available: 1.4.1) : 1.4.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.17.0 (/Users/XXXXXX/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.13
   OS     : macOS Catalina
```

My app plugins:

```
[info] Found 9 Capacitor plugins for ios:
       @capacitor-community/admob@3.2.0
       @capacitor/app@1.0.2
       @capacitor/camera@1.0.3
       @capacitor/filesystem@1.0.2
       @capacitor/haptics@1.0.2
       @capacitor/keyboard@1.0.2
       @capacitor/splash-screen@1.0.2
       @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.2
       @capacitor/storage@1.0.3
[info] Found 3 Cordova plugins for ios:
       cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing@6.0.3
       es6-promise-plugin@4.2.2
       onesignal-cordova-plugin@2.11.4
```

Comment: there is a solution for this case which is setting launchShowDuration: 30000 and in this.platform.ready().then(() => { // settimeout for 1500ms, and hide splash, this is 100% guarantied that no whte screen will occur, we put 1500 mostly for android devices since devices before sdk less than 25 are a bit slower in case there is complicated plugins added such as advanced http  });

Comment: `SplashScreen.hide()` in your response for Auth Check.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib - thanks for pointing this out. I had originally thought this may be the issue, however, no matter if a token is present or not, the white screen appears.

Comment: Remove `SplashScreen.hide()` from `initializeApp()` function and add it to your Token Validation API.

Comment: The solution Mostafa Harb provided works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do after platform ready just wrap the splash screen block code with setTimeout of 500ms.

Comment: I was hoping to find a different solution that setTimeout. It seems like a crutch approach to something that should work out of the box. Maybe others don’t think so?